# I need help understanding a simple JavaScript script

Tags: javascript

```
if(document.frmMain.POL_NO.value == "")
{
    alert("Select Policy Number");
    document.frmMain.ENDT_NO.value="";
    document.frmMain.POL_NO.focus();
    return false;           
}
```

Can anyone explain the above code to me? I am new to Javascript.

Comment: Please choose a more meaningful title next time.

Comment: Don't change any code until you get literate with Javascript + DOM Manipulation + HTML

Comment: The code snippet is very familiar to me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears to be a bit of validation code to make sure a user has entered a value for an item referred to as "Policy Number". It is the sort of code that gets called when submitting a form to check that the values the user has entered are valid.

In detail:

```
if(document.frmMain.POL_NO.value == "")
```

Only run this code if the item called in POL_NO the form called frmMain doesn't have a value yet.

```
alert("Select Policy Number");
```

Display a message to tell the user that they need to enter a value.

```
document.frmMain.ENDT_NO.value="";
```

Set the ENDT_NO item of frmMain to a blank value.

```
document.frmMain.POL_NO.focus();
```

Set the focus to the POL_NO item (the same as the user tabbing to it or clicking on it).

```
return false;
```

Return false to the code that called the function that this code is in. If this code is used in the event handler for the submit button on a form then returning false will stop the form from being submitted to the server until the POL_NO item has a value.

Answer (score 3):

If the contents of the item `POL_NO` from the form `frmMain` is empty, then throw an alert and change the value of the `ENDT_NO` item value to nothing (empty) and after that focus on the element `POL_NO`. Return `false` after that (I assume this code executes at `onSubmit` event, so the form won't be submitted if `POL_NO` doesn't have a value)

Probably the logic is that the `ENDT_NO` can't have a value if `POL_NO` is empty.

Enjoy!

Comment: The code is probably an event handler (probably onsubmit for the form) so the `return false` will abort the form submission.

Also this code is rather IE specific and will probably not work on many standard browsers. You should use `document.getElementById("frmMain").elements["POL_NO"]` instead of `document.frmMain.POL_NO`

Comment: that code is fine for all browsers. You can refer to a form by *name* like that. There'll be a form on that page defined like this: `<form name="frmMain">`. Accessing the input elements like that is fine too.

Comment: @nickf It's not fine at all. Best to choose standard-compliant methods over properietary or non-standard ones (which form access off of document really is, coming from the early DOM0 days).

Answer (score 3):

### HTML document

your HTML document has this defined somewhere in its content

```
<form id="frmMain" ...>
    <input type="..." id="POL_NO">
    <input type="..." id="ENDT_NO">
</form>
```

### SCRIPT code

So. Your script checks whether your `POL_NO` input field has a value.

1. If it doesn't (it's an empty string),
2. it displays an alert (information window) and
3. empties `ENDT_NO` field's value and
4. puts focus on the `POL_NO` field - so the user can immediately start selecting/typing a value in this field
5. returns false - probably to cancel form submission

### Business logic

Based on the logic of this script, the business process obviously doesn't allow any value in `ENDT_NO` field, until there's a value in `POL_NO`.

### Observation

If you need to change something about this code (if there's a bug in it), **I strongly suggest** you get to know Javascript/DOM/HTML before doing any changes.

Answer (score 3):

`document.frmMain` is a form in the page, and `POL_NO` and `ENDT_NO` are fields in the form, presumably listboxes.

This code is a simple validation script to make sure you filled out the form correctly.

```
//if POL_NO hasn't been set (no policy number selected):
if(document.frmMain.POL_NO.value == "")
{
    //show a message box
    alert("Select Policy Number");

    //clear the value (if any) of ENDT_NO
    document.frmMain.ENDT_NO.value="";

    //set the form focus to POL_NO (select it, as if you had clicked on it)
    document.frmMain.POL_NO.focus();

    //stop the form from being submitted
    return false;               
}
```

I'm assuming this code is part of a function which is called by `frmMain`'s `onSubmit` event (and event handler) -- when the function returns `false` the submit is cancelled. Were this not here, it would show the message box, clear `ENDT_NO`, select `POL_NO` and then submit anyways.

Note that referencing members of a form in the `document.formName.fieldName.property` fashion is deprecated. The correct way is to use `getElementById` or a similar function:

```
document.frmMain.ENDT_NO.value = "";           //bad
document.getElementById("ENDT_NO").value = ""; //correct
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code does a pretty simple validation, just read the code and find the fields POL_NO and ENDT_NO in your HTML output. Here is my comments :

```
// if your POL_NO field is empty, 
if(document.frmMain.POL_NO.value == "")
{
 // warn user that he need to select Policy number
 alert("Select Policy Number");
  // set ENDT_NO field's value to empty
 document.frmMain.ENDT_NO.value="";
 // set POL_NO active - focussed
 document.frmMain.POL_NO.focus();
 return false;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the value of the input named POL_NO in the form frmMain is empty, then show a message "Select Policy Number", empty the input named ENDT_NO, give the focus to the input named POL_NO, and the exit the function with the return value "false".